# How do I sync between iCal and Outlook Mac?

Tags: google-calendar, calendar.app, microsoft-outlook-2011

My iCal Calendar successfully shows Google Calendar events.  But those events are not syncing to Mac Outlook 2011.

Conversely, the Outlook events are showing up in ICal, but they are not showing up on my Google Calendar.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I got it to work was by using [Spanning Sync](http://www.spanningsync.com).

> Spanning Sync 3 is the one app that syncs both iCal with Google Calendar and Address Book with Google Contacts
>
> Update: as of 7/24/2012, Spanning Sync has announced the end of life of their product. More details here: http://blog.spanningsync.com/2012/07/end-of-the-line-for-spanning-sync.html

Comment: Could you please add a bit of info to your answer, explaining what Spanning Sync is and how it works? We like to have at least a brief explanation of what lies behind any links.